# In my sink pop-up stopper, the tip of the pivot rod is broken, how do I fix it?

Tags: sink

[image]

In my bathroom, the tip of the pivot rod which is connected to the stopper is broken. When the stopper goes down, it has no rod to hook to. Is it possible to re-use and re-adjust the existing pivot rod?

If not, should I get a new one?  Which name should I use to describe the hardware that I need when I go to the hardware store?

Comment: Thank you. The diagram was very useful. With my British set up, which has slight differences, the plastic sleeve had lost its adjustment screw. With the help of your drawing, I was able to disconnect the rod and remove and replace the plastic sleeve. To get a plumber in would have cost £150 or thereabouts. Thank you, again, for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have actually snapped the rod but have enough length to spare you should be able to move it forwards, however are you sure this has happened?

The reason I ask is that I had similar symptoms, but all that had happened is that the rod had slipped back through the clevis strap so it no longer connected with the stopper. The clip holding it to the strap made it look like it was just broken, but I eventually figured it out.

Admittedly, on mine there is no hook holding the rod to the stopper, it simply pushes the stopper up, and gravity lets it fall again when you pull the plunger up.

Comment: When I took out the stopper, there was about 1cm of metal rod that was hanging with dirty floss.  I assume the rod rotted and broke at the end. Can the rod actually slip through that ball like shape or is it glued to it?

Comment: On mine the ball is not fixed to the rod, so you can pull it all the way through.

Comment: In the photo, the spring is on the left of the clevis strap.  Is that the proper orientation?  I've managed to place the replacement but cannot make it tight.  Pulling and pushing the button is loose. Any tips on how to make the push and pull motion tight?

Comment: I have seen two setups - one with the spring clip on the left of the strap, and one with a clip on both sides. I wouldn't expect it to be very tight, but it shouldn't be so loose that it comes apart.

Comment: @ThierryLam I generally put the spring clip on both sides of the strap. This prevents it from sliding off. It is a little tricky, but basically all you have to do is slide the clip on to the rod and then insert the rod through the hole in the clevis strap, and then squeeze the spring clip over the end of the rod. This will allow the strap to move a little, but not too much.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you to the guy who mentioned it took a hammer to slide the ball down the rod to provide extra length after the end of the rod broke off.

I had to take a hammer and bang the rod further through the ball to get the 1/2inch extra length I needed. I put the broken end down through my wooden porch slats(providing a hard but not damaging holder for the ball) and hammered the long end of the rod down thru the ball. It took some effort as the ball was pretty stuck on the rod but it did slide down securely and did not slip thru like it was too loose. I got my extra length I needed without having to buy another one and successfully reattached to the clevis rod. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This just happened to me, yes the little ball does slide on the rod, although it took a hammer to get it to move.  Pushing the ball down the rod 2 cm gave me enough rod for the stopper to start working again.