# How can I take the pop-up stopper out of my sink?

Tags: sink

I've found a few tutorials online and searched here, but the mechanism on my sink seems to be different from others I've found tutorials for. Here's the general apparatus (credit to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15456/in-my-sink-pop-up-stopper-the-tip-of-the-pivot-rod-is-broken-how-do-i-fix-it)):

[image: Diagram outlining how stoppers work in general and names of the different parts.]

The issue I'm having is where the pivot rod goes into the pipe under the sink. I need to remove the pivot rod in order to get the stopper out, but I can't figure out how to do that. Here's a picture of what it looks like:

[image: Picture of my specific apparatus.]

There are 2 "slots" across from each other, but I can't fit anything into both because the pivot rod itself is between them. How can I get the pivot rod out of the pipe so I can remove the stopper?

Comment: The wings coming off the side look suspiciously like something to turn with.

Comment: @Comintern They're part of the fixed pipe. I'm not sure what they're there for, but I tried turning them before I asked.

Comment: That is bizarre - I've never seen a pop-up that you would need a spanner to get it apart with.  You can try placing a flat screwdriver against the top of one of the "slots" and tapping it counter-clockwise with a hammer to turn it, but keep in mind that it will be a lot easier to get apart than put back together that way.

Comment: I was kind of worried about how I'd get it back together after, even if I got it out.

Comment: Why do you need to get the stopper out? There might be other options depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need to snake the drain. It starts clogging almost immediately as soon as the water starts flowing. Someone already lent me the snake. I did just get it out using a screwdriver like you suggested; I'll try snaking it and hopefully I can get it back in :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grip the nut with the 2 'slots' and turn it counter-clockwise until it spins off and you can pull the pivot rod backwards enough to release the plunger. Reverse the process to put it back together.

A plastic setup like that is designed to twist off by hand. If it seems too tight simply use a pair of pliers to grab it and turn it.

Good luck!

Comment: You might have to disconnect the trap first for clearance.